# Wordpress is ignoring my post rewrite rule

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting

I have the following code to change *Posts* to *News*, and add `news-insights` to the URL of every post:

```
function cp_change_post_object() {
  $get_post_type = get_post_type_object('post');
  $labels = $get_post_type->labels;
  $labels->name = 'News & Insights';
  $labels->singular_name = 'News';
  $labels->add_new = 'Add News';
  $labels->add_new_item = 'Add News';
  $labels->edit_item = 'Edit News';
  $labels->new_item = 'News';
  $labels->view_item = 'View News';
  $labels->search_items = 'Search News';
  $labels->not_found = 'No News found';
  $labels->not_found_in_trash = 'No News found in Trash';
  $labels->all_items = 'All News';
  $labels->menu_name = 'News & Insights';
  $labels->name_admin_bar = 'News & Insights';
}
add_action( 'init', 'cp_change_post_object' );

function modify_post_type_post() {
  $post_type = 'post';
  $post_type_object = get_post_type_object($post_type);
  $post_type_object->has_archive = true;
  $post_type_object->rewrite = array('slug' => 'news-insights', 'with_front' => false);

  register_post_type($post_type, $post_type_object);
};
add_action('init', 'modify_post_type_post');
```

Everything is working correctly, including the `has_archive` declaration, but the URLs are not being rewritten. They're still top-level (domain.com/news-slug). My permalink setting is on *Post name*. Flushing permalinks has no effect, and all other custom post type URL rewrites are working as expected. What's going on?

Comment: You can use the [`register_post_type_args`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/register_post_type_args/) filter to change the post type declaration, also `post` post type.  ["Is there possible way to modify custom post type?"](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/342540)

Comment: This isn't a custom post type, it's the default "post". Some args in register_post_type_args appear to have no effect on the default post type

Answer (score 0):

Sorted this out. In my case, I had Category base also set to `news-insights`, so Wordpress was trying to find a category with the slug of the post. Removing the category base solved the issue.